# nexus how to avoid packages with quarantine

Tags: security, conda, nexus

I am using Conda with Nexus and having issues with files that are quarantined. When I run conda install package_name, sometimes I get errors that cause the conda command to fail.

Ex:

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 403 REQUESTED ITEM IS QUARANTINED for url <https://nexus.xxxx.com/repository/XXXX_CONDA_BASE/linux-64/openssl-1.1.1i-h27cfd23_0.conda>
```

Is there a way to run Conda commands with Nexus repo's to ignore quarantined files, find another version, and continue to run? My current workaround is to include or exclude these specific quarantined versions as I find them. This can become cumbersome when there are several quarantined files in one install command, especially likely when there is a large list of dependencies.

Comment: I think that may be as designed.  Without knowing more details I believe Nexus Lifecycle may be able to help you...have you spoken to anyone at Sonatype about it?  It's possible you just have the wrong product for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to find a better solution, but for now I found some workaround way to fix this.

I added an item to the conda pinned file with a version of openssl that has been released from quarantine.

```
...
openssl=1.1.1h
...
```

Another option available is to add this same package and version to every conda install command I run.

A third option is to include this command instead: --no-update-deps, but this may be overkill as it may affect other packages and versions selected by conda.